Clustering custom icons in Font-Awesome style
A previous topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75526891/custom-icons-in-font-awesome-style-r-leaflet?newreg=026c290b4abe44f58cc3d9a9bb490e39 
I've been working through the same problem with my maps and using custom icons that are not available to makeAwesomeIcon. However in my work I have multiple datapoints on the same location and so wish to cluster them using clusterOptions from leaflet, and it appears the addAwesomeMarkers() item gets overwritten by the AddMarkers() item in this scenario.
I have modified the reproducible code in the previous topic below, clustering the first 5 datapoints for testing, and also added the clusterOptions to the map.
I need to be able to display the icons on top of the markers, not overwrite them.
library(dplyr)
library(fontawesome) 

data <- head(quakes,20)
groups <- rep(c(1,2,3,4),each=5)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(data,groups))

# Update lat and long of rows 2-5 to match row 1
data[2:5, c("lat", "long")] <- data[1, c("lat", "long")]

markers <- awesomeIconList(
  `1` = makeAwesomeIcon(
    icon="empty",
    markerColor = "white",
    library="fa"
  ),
  `2` = makeAwesomeIcon(
    icon="empty", 
    markerColor ="pink",
    library="fa"
  ),
  `3`  = makeAwesomeIcon(
    icon="empty", 
    markerColor ="red",
    library="fa"
  ),
  `4` = makeAwesomeIcon(
    icon="empty", 
    markerColor ="blue",
    library="fa"
  )
)

icons <- iconList(
  `1` = makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/503906/ice-cream.svg",
    iconWidth = 31*215/230,
    iconHeight = 20, 
    iconAnchorY = 33,
    iconAnchorX = 31*215/230/2
  ),
  `2` = makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/39019/donut.svg",
    iconWidth = 31*215/230,
    iconHeight = 20, 
    iconAnchorY = 33,
    iconAnchorX = 31*215/230/2
  ),
  `3` = makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/500813/coffee.svg",
    iconWidth = 31*215/230,
    iconHeight = 20, 
    iconAnchorY = 33,
    iconAnchorX = 31*215/230/2
  ),
  `4` = makeIcon(
    iconUrl = "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/111427/shawarma.svg",
    iconWidth = 31*215/230,
    iconHeight = 20, 
    iconAnchorY = 33,
    iconAnchorX = 31*215/230/2
  )
)

data %>% leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addAwesomeMarkers(lat = ~lat, lng = ~long, popup = ~as.character(mag), icon = ~ markers[groups],
                    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
                      spiderfyOnMaxZoom = TRUE,    
                      showCoverageOnHover = TRUE,
                      zoomToBoundsOnClick = TRUE,   
                      spiderfyDistanceMultiplier = 2.0,     
                    )) %>% 
  addMarkers(lat = ~lat, lng = ~long, popup = ~as.character(mag), icon = ~ icons[groups],       
                    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
                      spiderfyOnMaxZoom = TRUE,    
                      howCoverageOnHover = TRUE, 
                      zoomToBoundsOnClick = TRUE,   
                      spiderfyDistanceMultiplier = 2.0,
                    ))


Ended up finding a workaround to this problem, which was to use the built in 'shadow' functionality in the makeIcon() function to combine the pin and icon into a singular icon.
Example below:
syringe = makeIcon(
  iconUrl = https://www.svgrepo.com/show/482909/syringe.svg,
  iconWidth = 30,
  iconHeight = 20, 
  iconAnchorY = 35,
  iconAnchorX = 15,
  shadowUrl = https://www.svgrepo.com/show/512650/pin-fill-sharp-circle-634.svg,
  shadowWidth = 50,           
  shadowHeight = 40,          
  shadowAnchorY = 40,         
  shadowAnchorX = 20,
  popupAnchorX = 0.1,
  popupAnchorY = -40
)

